# Excel VBA - How to define Prop in ThisWorkbook.ContentTypeProperties?

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I have an excel workbook that has properties that are from Sharepoint. I am trying to iterate through the properties through the use of

```
 For Each Prop In ThisWorkbook.ContentTypeProperties
```

However, I am getting an error saying "Variable not defined".

The strange thing is I have another workbook that also iterates through the properties and that is working fine.

Does anyone know where I could be going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error "Variable not defined" might be easy to fix. Does the code [declare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dim-statement) the variable Prop?

```
 Dim Prop As MetaProperty
```

Also, be sure that [ThisWorkbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.thisworkbook) is what you want.

Comment: Sorry to bring up an old thread but this worked for me. Thank you!